# What grades do I have?

Tags: graduate-admissions, grades

In a two months I will have a bachelors degree from a German University with an degree average (Notendurchschnitt) of 1.8 or 1.9 . My programme uses ECTS Credit Points.
I am in the process of applying to British MSc programmes. They mostly require a Honours degree of "2:1" which, according to one university, is equivalent to "GPA 3.0".

Do I pass these requirements? And is it legit for me to say in my application that I have a GPA of 1.9?

I tried to get my head around these degree specifications but was unable to.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what university you will apply for. However, because the Msc is expensive in the UK, even for the British students, the students tend to look for jobs after Bsc; and therefore some universities accept students with lower grades.

Little bit of advice: Look for the courses in details to cover your interests; For example an Msc in Computer Science at one university might involve more than theory; than the same Msc at another university.

Comment: I have covered my finance and will be able to pay the tuition. However I still have the problem that I don't know how to convert my German grades to British grades.
And my question shouldn't mean that I apply just about everywhere. I have a selection of 5 prefered courses on which I have done some research.

Comment: 2.1 is getting an average of 60% to 70% over 100% of all marks. Is your GPA from 3 (being 100%)?

Comment: I am not sure what "GPA from 3" means. In Germany grades are between 1 and 6 with one decimal digit. 1 is the best, 6 is the worst and 4 is the minimum passing grade.

Comment: This might help: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9058/how-to-convert-from-one-grading-scheme-to-another