# How to convert Australian grade to US GPA?

Tags: united-states, grading, gpa, australia

I am wondering how to convert Australian grade(HD, D, C, ...) to US GPA (A+, A, B, C ...)
I tried few websites but those showed me which I think of as "too good to be true" results. 
For example, according to the website I used, a grade of C in Australian grading system is equivalent to B grade in US.

Is that realistic? and is there a formula to convert ?

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of [http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9058/how-to-convert-from-one-grading-scheme-to-another](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9058/how-to-convert-from-one-grading-scheme-to-another)

Comment: HD=4, D=3, C=2, D=1. Say, if you studied four units (you got HD,D,C,D in the exam respectively), your GPA should be (3x4+3x3+3x2+3x1)/(3x4)

Comment: @DavidWashington If you refer to this website http://www.foreigncredits.com/Resources/Grade-Conversion/, it shows a different conversion. Are you sure about the conversion you proposed ?

Comment: @Noushad, that was the one I found on Monash's web.