# GPA in MBA programme?

Tags: masters, gpa

I notice that when someone asks about GPA, they usually mean an undergraduate GPA.  Is there GPA for a masters degree or MBA?  If not, how a student's performance is measured (in UK and US)?

Answer (score 2):

In the US, a student's performance is typically indicated by GPA from high school through doctoral-level study.

In the UK, a student's performance is indicated by "[degree classification](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8170/converting-from-and-to-british-grading-scheme)" levels for undergraduate and taught masters programs. (The names of the degree levels are different for masters courses than for undergraduate courses.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a GPA for M.S and PhD degrees. In my experience, sometimes I see the following: Candidate X applies to University X for its PhD program with an undergraduate GPA or 3.2 and then a M.S GPA of 4.0 (I have seen similar things). Although Candidate X recovers makes up for their performance during their M.S. years, since University X is a high ranked university, they reject Candidate X. Candidate X still has a relatively successful applications cycle, although not by necessarily tier 1 universities.

I understand that a lot more goes into graduate admissions than just GPA, but this is kind of a trend that I have seen. There obviously could be more to it, and it makes for an interesting report where one can analyse dependency here.